# SSMS Add in - accessing Results Pane

Tags: c#, ssms, ssms-addin

I am attempting to write a SSMS add in (either 2008 R2 or 2012) in C#.
The goal is to allow right clicking on a field in the results pane, and have the context menu provide pre-written queries based on the field selected.

I have successfully created a basic SSMS addin, but I need help through my code, gaining access to the results pane object, and more specifically, the field name and value of the cell the user right clicked on and then adding options to the context menu.

Thanks
Rod

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, it is helpful if you supply code that others can refer to. It will help you get answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Did you find the solution. I'll be happy to know how to.

Comment: @Itay.B Hi! Has anyone found the solution to this?

Comment: @OttO I searched all over the place and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if you got this working, but I've got part way to what you want.  You need the GUID for the window, then attach to the events that window is throwing up.

I'm sure its possible, just how much blood sweat and tears you spend on it...

In the code in here http://ssmsaddin2012.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SSMSAddinDenali/Addin/Connect.cs

I link up to as many events as I can.  I dont know if its any help.